# Hibernate persist() method

Tags: java, hibernate

Is the below statement a valid one?

`persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries`

When I try the below code using persist; then the row is getting inserted without any transaction (It is commented out).

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("student.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    //Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();

    /*
     * Persist is working without transaction boundaries ===> why?
     */

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("xxx");
    student.setLastName("yyy");
    student.setCity("zzz");
    student.setState("ppp");
    student.setCountry("@@@");
    student.setId("123456");
            session.persist(student);
            //tran.commit();
            session.flush();
    session.close();
```

Comment: Please use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: How is the db connection configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries

This statement is correct. When control returns from `persist()` back to your code, no `INSERT` statements have been executed. These statements are guaranteed to be deferred until session flushing. Note that `persist()` would be a pointless method if no insert happened **ever**.

Comment: In that case, when the control returns from `save()` also, no `INSERT` statements are fired, they are fired only while flushing the session. Then in that case `save()` and `persist()` both are having the same behaviour right?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK data is saving because of session.flush(), try after removing this, mostly you will get an error.

[Hibernate persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168950/spring-hibernate-persist-does-not-result-in-insert)

[Diff. save & persist](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/difference-between-hibernate-save-and-persist-methods/)